# Apache 2.2 - CSS and JS not loading on first request

Tags: apache-2.2, java

I am not a network administrator and have very least knowledge of deploying Java Web Application on Apache 2.2 with ssl configured. So please ignore any wrong interpretation in the question.

We are having our Java web application deployed on the apache 2.2 and all the static content(resources) are there in the **htdocs** folder in apache 2.2 installation directory like CSS, images and js.

The problem is that when a user opens a new browser session and accessing the application( very first request to the server), we have our login page to display. But when the first request completes loading the page is not loading the CSS, images and JS required. But if the user refreshes the page again then everything is there and after that everything is working very smoothly. The problem is only while serving the very first request by a user.

Am I missing some important configuration? Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.